# Importing in React JS

Tags: reactjs

What is the difference between

```
import Something from 'react';
```

and

```
import {Something} from 'react';
```

What does those curly braces means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`import Something from 'react';`

imports what is the `default` exported of a module.
In this case the export should be like

`export default const Something = function(){...}`

`import {Something} from 'react';` imports a named export, like

`export const Something = function(){}`

If your module has both `default` and named exports you can import them in a single like. Example

```
//module A
export default const Something = function(){}
export const SomethingElse = function(){}
```

And then import them like

```
//module B

import Something, { SomethingElse } from 'moduleA';
```

In the previous like you dont have to import the `default` as `Something`, you can import it with whatever name you want.

`import A from 'moduleA'`

is equal to

`import Something from 'moduleA'`

Comment: You can also pull the named exports in the same line. For example:

import React, { Component } from 'react';

Comment: @JoshuaSlate I am updating the answer